# Giving the tag name from a variable in flex

Tags: apache-flex, tags

I have bound some xml data to a view in flex. Now from that view I'm going to access those data using the following code.

```
data.@tag1
```

This is working, but what I really want is to assign the @tag from a variable as follows.

```
var tag:String = "@tag"+count;  //count is a number
data.tag;
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data[tag].

```
var xml:XML = <root tag1="as3" tag2="ftw"/>
for (var i:int=0; i<2; i++){
    var tag:String = "@tag"+(i+1);
    trace(xml[tag]);
}
```

//as3 ftw